# Dealing with final built-in classes with no-args constructor in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I had created the following `Garde` class which has `beginDate` and `endDate` of the `java.time.LocalDateTime` type as fields

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "garde")
public class Garde {
    private LocalDateTime beginDate, endDate;
    //constructors and methods
  }
```

when I try to marshall the `Garde` list I get this exception :

```
No default constructor found on class java.time.LocalDateTime
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.time.LocalDateTime.<init>() 
....
```

I tried to create another class that extends `java.time.LocalDateTime` with no-args constructor, but it didn't work because `LocalDateTime` class is final, so how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `XmlAdapter` and configure it using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.

Something along the lines:

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends 
    XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String value) {
        return value == null ? null : LocalDatTime.parse(value);
    }
    // ...
}
```

And in your class:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocaDateTime beginDate;
```

You can also apply the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)})` annotation to the `package-info.java`.

Comment: but what do I put in the `marshal` and `unmarchal` methods body in the `LocalDateTimeAdapter` class?

Comment: Parse `String` to `LocalDateTime` in `unmarshal` (like I sketched), serialize `LocalDateTime` to `String` in `marshal`. Should be pretty trivial.

Comment: it works fine when changing `XmlAdapter<LocalDateTime, String>` to `XmlAdapter<String,LocalDateTime>`